# Why 'the' is incorrectly used here?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

Bilingualism is an additional skill that can give an added advantage in career or
the cognitive development. Some opine that it must be developed easily in life, while others suggest to learn it once a child is grown enough. I believe that the language skills must be imbibed from the start of school.

The issue in below: 
**the cognitive development 

the language skills**

Comment: It sounds natural to forgo the use of 'article' here.Specifically, you are talking about 'cognitive development' and 'language skills' in general terms here.The use of "the" implies the particularity of the two items, which isn't something the extract seems to suggest.

Comment: In a career or in cognitive development . . . language skills.

Comment: The passage as a whole has problems, not just the articles. *An added advantage in career*? *It must be developed **easily** in life*?  *Suggest to learn it*? *Language skills must be* ***imbibed***?

Comment: I second Jason Bassford here. Barring the first item he has highlighted, which doesn't seem to have a glaring error, the other items are ill-phrased and even catachrestic. Thus "easily", "suggest to", and "imbibed" should go out and "early", "suggest that", and "inculcated" should go in.

Comment: @Stockfish -Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @JasonBassford - I see there are lot of mistakes. Thanks for your reply.